# How to connect from Windows through SSH using another Windows PC as a proxy?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ssh, proxy, putty

I have an embedded Linux machine to which I can connect only from a certain Windows PC (let's call it WinLab) with Putty through SSH. And to WinLab machine I can connect through Remote Desktop from my Windows workstation.

How can I setup somehow an SSH proxy or something similar on WinLab PC (it is Windows) so I could just run Putty on my workstation to whatever address so in the end I would connect to Linux machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called as **SSH tunneling** in putty. Check this link - https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

So you can install putty in the Windows PC which connects to the Linux Machine and enable the SSH tunneling to the port which you want to access e.g., **22 for SSH**. You just have to provide the corresponding port in the Windows PC like e.g., **8080**.

Now in putty of the second windows system connect/telnet to 8080 form your first windows system which forwards the request to you Linux machine.

More examples: http://www.silvertree.org/smtp_tunnel.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't do it. First of all, how do these Putty tunneling work - is it global setting i.e. I need to add port forwarding once and that's it for all sessions? Or it only per putty session? Do I need to keep putty connection open on the proxy PC or it would work without opening putty? And should I use IP of the target linux PC on my workstation or the IP of proxy PC?

Comment: Its per putty session. So the putty connection needs to be open on the PC which directly connects to the Linux machine for you to access it from anywhere else. It will not work with out this putty connection which does a SSH tunneling. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have another issue now - I have open and working PuTTY SSH session on proxy PC. And on my workstation it seems that I can connect to proxy. Because when I close PuTTY on proxy on my pc I see immediately message "Server unexpectedly closed connection". The problem is - when connection is established (I think) the only thing I see on my pc is black PuTTY window, without command prompt. Enter key or any other don't affect it.

Comment: That happens when there is a timeout. Even I have faced the issue. I have not checked for a solution as I only need it for few minutes for test purpose.